# How can we dynamically control CSS animation duration?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a slider. Based on that slider value, the duration of the animation has to be controlled.

Here is my code:

```
function getval(val)
{
    $('body').css("-webkit-animation-duration",val)
}
```

The above function is the `onchange` event handler for the slider. I would like to know how could we dynamically control the CSS animation duration?

Comment: And what seems to be going wrong?